# How can i use the useSWR hook when my response need to do some logical operations before next dependant API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, swr

I'm using `swr` in a CRA app and need to use the `useSWR` hook for data fetching that is both dependant and conditional. What i need to do is:

1. Call an api to get an `id` which i will use for a second api call. the `id` is located in either `upcomingEvents` or `passedEvents` .
2. I want to get it from `upcomingEvents` but if that array is empty i want to get it from `passedEvents`.
3. I know i want the first id in either of the arrays, so using the first index of either array is ok (ex: `upcomingEvents[0].id`).
4. Here is an example of the code and the response from the first api call:

```js
const { data: result } = useSWR(`${BASE_URL}/event/${searchEvent}`);
// this second call will wait and run when the first call resolves
const { data: event, error } = useSWR(() => `${BASE_URL}/project/${result.upcomingEvents[0].id}`);
```

response from first call where i want to get the id for the next call could look like this:

```json
{
  "upcomingEvents": [{"id": "1234"}, {"id": "5678"}, {"id": "0909"}],
  "passedEvents": [{"id": "0987"}, {"id": "6543"}]
}
```

if i hard code the second api call to use the `upcomingEvents[0].id` (like in the code example above) i get the response i want.

What i struggle with is where to put the logic that determines which of the id's to use in the depending second api call? I want this logic but can't figure out where without breaking the rules of hooks

```js
  const { data: result } = useSWR(`${BASE_URL}/event/${searchEvent}`);
  const { data: event, error } = useSWR(() =>
   result.upcomingEvents.length > 0
     ? `${BASE_URL}/project/${result.upcomingEvents[0].id}`
     : `${BASE_URL}/project/${result.passedEvents[0].id}`
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

- separate two `useSWR` requests into separate functions
- pass `null` key into second `useSWR()` when returned value from the first `useSWR` is falsy. This will ensure the second fetch is skipped if the first one hasn't finished yet.

```
 const fetcher = url => fetch(url).then(r => r.json())
 
 const useEvents = () => {
  const { data } = useSWR(`${BASE_URL}/event/${searchEvent}`, fetcher);
  return data;
 };
 
 const useEventDetails = () => {
   const events = useEvents();
   let endpoint;

   if (!events) {
     endpoint = null
   }
   else {
    endpoint = events.upcomingEvents.length > 0 ?
     `${BASE_URL}/project/${result.upcomingEvents[0].id}`
     `${BASE_URL}/project/${result.passedEvents[0].id}`;
   }
   
   const { data } = useSWR(endpoint, fetcher);
   return data;
 }
```